# Any way to disable the "new and improved" Rich Text Editor?

Tags: richtextarea

The new rich text editor takes my existing data (which currently includes single 
 line breaks, per the old standard) and changes it to`<p></p>` designation.  While it certainly "looks" better, I don't like the functionality where I cannot have single spacing.  Since I render this data onto my quote documents, appearance matters.  I'm also concerned that it will double the amount of space used on a field that is already sometimes overwhelmingly populated...  How can I remove this monstrosity and get back my old, simple editor??